# Mascara JS e HTML não funcionam

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tentei das duas formas (js e html) e tentei também unindo as duas, como representada abaixo, mas mesmo assim ela não funciona.
PS: Vou usar todas essas mascaras, mas se tiver algum problema nelas pode mudar tudo, menos o id.
Código:

```
session_start();
include_once 'config.php';
include_once 'class/BD.class.php';

if (isset($_GET['post']) && $_GET['post'] != '') {
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
  $dataLog = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
  $nomeLog = $_SESSION['nome'];
  $cpfLog = $_SESSION['cpf'];
  $tabela = $_SESSION['editar'];

  if (isset($_SESSION['editar']) && $_SESSION['editar'] == "cadastro") {

    $cpf = strip_tags($_GET["post"]);
    $buscaContri = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `cadastro` WHERE `cpf` = '$cpf'");
    $buscaContri->execute();
    $contaContri = $buscaContri->rowCount();
    $resultaContri = $buscaContri->fetchObject();

    if (isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'editarDados') {

      //CADASTRO

      $nome         = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome'));
      $cpf          = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cpf'));
      $rg           = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rg'));
      $sexo        = $_POST['sexo'];
      $nascimento   = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nascimento'));
      $naturalidade = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'naturalidade'));
      $logradouro   = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'logradouro'));
      $bairro       = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'bairro'));
      $cep          = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cep'));
      $cidade       = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cidade'));
      $fone         = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fone'));
      $email        = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email'));
      $mae          = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mae'));
      $pai          = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pai'));
      $titulo         = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'titulo'));
      $secao         = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'secao'));

      include_once('incs/valida-cpf-cnpj.php');

      $cpf_cnpj = new ValidaCPFCNPJ($cpf);
      $formatado = $cpf_cnpj->formata();
      if ($formatado) {


        $upCad = BD::conn()->prepare("UPDATE `cadastro` SET nome = '$nome', cpf = '$cpf', rg = '$rg', sexo = '$sexo', nascimento = '$nascimento', naturalidade = '$naturalidade', logradouro = '$logradouro', bairro = '$bairro', cep = '$cep', cidade = '$cidade', fone = '$fone', email = '$email', mae = '$mae', pai = '$pai', titulo = '$titulo', secao = '$secao' WHERE cpf = '$cpf'");
        //echo "UPDATE `feirantes` SET cpf = '$cpf', rg = '$rg', nome = '$nome', endereco = '$endereco', setor = '$setor', vm2 = '$vm2', fone = '$fone', banca = '$banca', dia = '$dia', natureza = '$natureza', fiscal = '$fiscal'";
        $upAlt = BD::conn()->prepare("INSERT INTO `alteracao`(`nome`, `data`, `cpf`, `tabela`, `cpfalt`) VALUES ('$nomeLog', '$dataLog', '$cpfLog', '$tabela', '$cpf')");
        //echo "INSERT INTO `alteracao`(`nome`, `data`, `cpf`, `tabela`, `cpfalt`) VALUES ('$nomeLog', '$dataLog', '$cpfLog', '$tabela', '$cpf')";

        if ($upCad->execute() and $upAlt->execute()) {
          //$sucesso = 'Edição realizada com sucesso ';
        } else {
          //$erro = 'Não foi possível editar! Tente Novamente!';
        }
      } else {
        $erro = 'Você tentou cadastrar um CPF / CNPJ invalido, dados excluídos!';
      }
    }


?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br" xml:lang="pt-br">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="description" content="Página para realizar login">
      <meta name="author" content="Marcelo Marcos Santos">
      <link rel="icon" href="imagens/favicon.ico">
      <title>Capela</title>
      <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#data").mask("99/99/9999", {reverse: true});
          $("#telefone").mask("(99)99999-9999");
          $("#NIS").mask("00000000000");
          $("#secao").mask("0000");
          $("#titulo").mask("000000000000/00");
          $("#cep").mask("00000-000");
          $("#rg").mask("00 000 000-0");
          $("#cpf").mask("000.000.000-00");
          $("#SUS").mask("000000000000000");
        })
      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <?php
      if (isset($erro)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $erro . '</div>'; ?>
        <script>
          setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = "http://atriossys.com.br/capela/sistema/consultacpf.php";
          }, 5000);
        </script>
      <?php }
      if (isset($sucesso)) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><h4>' . $sucesso . '</h4></div>'; ?>
        <script>
          setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = "http://atriossys.com.br/capela/sistema/consultacpf.php";
          }, 5000);
        </script>
      <?php } ?>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row min600">

            <div class="col-md-12">

              <div class="oculta" id="site">
                <div id="main" class="container" style="min-height: 500px">

                  <div>
                    <h3 class="page-header"> </h3>
                    <div id="list" class="row">
                      <form action="" name="frmCadastro" method="post">
                        <div class="table-responsive col-md-12">
                          <br>
                          <h3>Dados Pessoais</h3><br>
                          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label name="">Nome</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resultaContri->nome ?>" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
                            <label name="">CPF</label>
                            <input name="cpf" type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" data-mask="000.000.000-00" value="<?php echo $resultaContri->cpf ?>" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label name="">RG</label>
                            <input type="text" name="rg" class="form-control" id="rg" data-mask="00 000 000-0" value="<?php echo $resultaContri->rg ?>" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label name="">Sexo</label><br>
                            <select name="sexo">
                              <option value="indefinido">Selecione seu sexo</option>
                              <option value="masculino">Masculino</option>
                              <option value="feminino">Feminino</option>
                              <option value="outro">Outro</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label>Nascimento</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nascimento" class="form-control" id="data" data-mask="99/99/9999" value="<?php echo $resultaContri->nascimento ?>" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label>Naturalidade</label>
                            <input type="text" name="naturalidade" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resultaContri->naturalidade ?>" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label>Logradouro</label>
                            <input type="text" name="logradouro" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resultaContri->logradouro ?>" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label>Bairro</label>
                            <input type="text" name="bairro" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resultaContri->bairro ?>" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label>CEP</label>
                            <input type="text" name="cep" class="form-control" id="cep" data-mask="00000-000" value="<?php echo $resultaContri->cep ?>" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label>Cidade</label>
                            <input type="text" name="cidade" class="form-control" value="Capela" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label>Telefone</label>
                            <input type="text" name="fone" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resultaContri->fone ?>" id="telefone" data-mask="(99)99999-9999" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label>E-mail</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resultaContri->email ?>" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label>Mãe</label>
                            <input type="text" name="mae" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resultaContri->mae ?>" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label>Pai</label>
                            <input type="text" name="pai" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resultaContri->pai ?>" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label>Titulo de Eleitor</label>
                            <input type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo" data-mask="000000000000/00" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resultaContri->titulo ?>" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                            <label>Zona/Seção</label>
                            <input type="text" name="secao" id="secao" data-mask="0000" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $resultaContri->secao ?>" />
                          </div>
                          <br>
                          <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                            <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" value="editarDados" name="acao" /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button></td>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div> <!-- /#list -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- /container -->
      </div>

    <?php } else {
    echo "Página não encontrada entre em contato com o Provedor!";
  }
}
```

Comment: Amigo, aonde está a chamada do arquivo/cdn mask?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {` deve exitir só um, pode por todas as atribuições de mask dentro da mesma function. Além disso e do que o @Azzi-Digicard comentou, essa sintaxe é jquery, imagino que saiba disso certo? pq ai tbm não vi a referencia para o script do jquery

Comment: @RicardoPontual Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @Azzi-Digicard Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Tente o seguinte:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>

</head> 
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.date').mask('00/00/0000' , {reverse: true});
    $('.time').mask('00:00:00');
    $('.cep').mask('00000-000');
    $('.phone').mask('(00) 00000-0000');
    $('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00');
    $('.money').mask('000.000.000.000,00');
});


</script> 

<label>DATA</label>
<input class="date">
<label>HORAS</label>
<input type="text" class="time">
<label>CEP</label>
<input type="text" class="cep">
<label>TELEFONE</label>
<input type="text" class="phone">
<label>CPF</label>
<input type="text" class="cpf">
<label>DINHEIRO</label>
<input type="text" class="money">


</body> 
</html>
```

Confere os campos certinho, precisa daqueles dois scripts lá em cima e precisa somente de um `$(document).ready(function(){...})`.